# Accessing a pointer from a structure pointer in C

Tags: c, embedded

I am trying to access an address of a pointer inside a pointer structure.

Below is the code I am trying. Kindly help.

```
struct NODE
{
    int Data;
    int *PtrInt;

} NODE_1, *PtrNode;

int main(void)
{
    NODE_1.Data = 100;
    NODE_1.PtrInt = 0x50;
    *(NODE_1.PtrInt) = 0x110;   // i am able to access pointer from structure here

    PtrNode = 0x1000;
    PtrNode->Data = 0x500;
    PtrNode->PtrInt = 0xff;
    *(PtrNode->PtrInt) = 0xcc;  // but i am not able to access to pointer from structure
                                // pointer
}
```

Comment: Are those the real pointer/addresses (*e.g.*, `0x50`, `0x1000` and `0xff`) you are using? Is this an embedded system? How do you know that the memory at `0x1000` has been reserved to hold your structure?

Comment: yes this is in embedded system. i am able to view it in memory that at 0x1000 address it is storing 0x500 and 0xff

Comment: `PtrNode->PtrInt = 0xff;` 0xff is possibly an invalid address for an int to be pointed at, depending on your hardware. Try using 0xfc or 0x100 instead.

Comment: yes i confirmed that values of structure are stored at address 0x1000 and yes 0xff was written at PtrNode->PtrInt

Comment: What does "i am not able to access.." **mean** ? Smoke starts pouring from your device?

Comment: I'm with @mah.  Try swapping the 0x50 and the 0xff.  If the error swaps too, then the problem is that you are not allowed to write bytes to 0xFF, either due to word addressing limitations or memory permissions

Comment: what processor is this?

Comment: yes i confirmed that values of structure are stored at address 0x1000 and yes 0xff was written at PtrNode->PtrInt after 0x500 for PtrNode->Data

Comment: @mah and AShelly i gave a different value to data part of PtrNode->PtrIntr namely 0x10 and and 0x20 for address part of PtrNode->PtrIntr  it worked Thanks a lot

Comment: its atmel 32 bit processor. One more question i would like to ask i.e., i am storing the structure pointer at address 0x1000 and i am storing a pointer inside a structure at address 0x20. here i am able to see the data value of PtrNode->PtrInt at address 0x1004 but i am not able to see the data value of PtrNode->PtrInt at address 0x20 since that's the address i have assigned to PtrNode->PtrInt.

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed through conversation in comments: the problem is that you're setting a pointer to point to address `0xff` and then trying to write/read an integer there. Your hardware is not tolerant of an integer value being accessed at an unaligned memory address such as 0xff; use an address with valid (according to your hardware) alignment and you'll be fine.